# Network is unreachable: connect

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After Upgrading to version 0.4.0 of Android Studio, I have started getting the following error when compiling my project:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':muve'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':muve:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+.
     Required by:
         MUVE:muve:unspecified
      > Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]'.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/'.
               > Network is unreachable: connect
```

My build.gradle file is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 18
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

I am at a loss on how to resolve the issue.  Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I have `mavenCentral()` in the repositories block in buildscript... Don't know if that is equivalent `maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }`

Comment: I have tried both...  Same error.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a networking problem, somewhere between you and Maven Central. Try again after a while, perhaps with `--refresh-dependencies`. I've you've successfully built with the same dependencies before, you can also try an offline build (`-o`).

Comment: Peter, thanks for replying... I am able to open the URLs listed in the error above in Chrome without issue.  However, the Android Studio consistently fails.

Comment: Try with Gradle command line build, to see if it makes a difference. Instead of `maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }`, always use `mavenCentral()`. If you are behind a proxy, see [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) for how to configure a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and check whether your studio can make connection successful with mention maven repository in error.

Go to File > Settings > HTTP proxy , select auto detect proxy settings just for test.

[image: checking connection]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using an HTTP proxy, and this was my .gradle/gradle.properties :

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=10.23.201.11
systemProp.http.proxyPort=3128
```

I changed it to HTTPS, even though I was using HTTP

```
systemProp.https.proxyPort=3128
systemProp.https.proxyHost=10.23.201.11
```

When I hit Sync, Android Studio Popped this:
[Android Studio Pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSVwq.png)

Uncheck the HTTPS proxy and then OK.

Comment: I also ran into this after I onced enabled the proxy when needed and then forgot to disable it later when outside of the proxy's network. Although I disabled the proxy in Android Studio, ~/.gradle/gradle.properties still contained the proxy settings.